# Optimal method to calculate Fractional Fourier for Chirp signals

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, estimation

There are several method exist in the literature to calculate fractional Fourier transform. My interest is in chirp signals and want to find time delay estimation using fractional Fourier transform (Frft). Can anyone point me which algorithm I should use to obtain Frft. I think Frft canbe calculated several ways, by Eigen decomposition , Hermite polynomial, chirp convolution etc.Any comment would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered calculating it like [in this paper](https://nalag.cs.kuleuven.be/papers/ade/frftcomp/preprint.pdf)? If you are interested in Chirps, calclulating FrFT would be used to estimate angle only?